# Taylor series for $x\over {\log(1-x)}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Well, I understand expansions, but here I would like to have a general term for the coefficients in $$\frac x{\log(1-x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$ Direct calculations gives me $$-1,\frac12,\frac1{12},\frac1{24},\frac{19}{720},...$$

I just fail to see a pattern! I appreciate any hints/comments. Many thanks.

Comment: Calculating the Cauchy product $$-1 = \Biggl(\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n x^n\Biggr)\cdot \Biggl(\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+1}x^k\Biggr)$$ might lead to a closed form. In any case, it leads to a recurrence.

Comment: Following Daniel Fischer's comment, one can get a recursive formula for the $a_i$ using the formulae in http://mathoverflow.net/a/53402/26266 .

Comment: @DanielFischer Many thanks. This is interesting. I alread have a recursive where I looked $\sum a_n x^n \times$ (expansion for $\frac{\log(1-x)}{x} $). But I was looking for a closed form expression for $a_n$. I will try this too, maybe this will be better.

Comment: @Travis this is interesting, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep transforming $f(x)$ into other functions $g(x)$ such that you can convert an explicit power series of $g(x)$ into one of $f(x)$, e.g.

- linear variable transforms,
- multiplications with powers of $x$,
- derivatives with respect to $x$.

I feel like $$k(x)=\frac{1}{1+\log(1+x)}$$ is a function where you can come up with a general form of $\frac{d^n}{dx}k(x)$ and therefore an explicit series. $1+\log(1+x)=\log(e\cdot(1+x))$ is a linear transform into $\log(1-x)$.

Comment: Interesting and many thank! though it seems to be shifting my variable $x$ to $ax+b$ which will then not be a expansion in $x$ but in $ax+b$. It also looks like that the derivatives of $k$ at zero are a bit messy and require again a recuerrent relationship to be defined ...

Comment: There is a systematic approach for finding a recurrent relationship for the coefficients (express $f'(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$ and $x$), but you will have to put in original creative work at some point for an explicit formula. If you know $f(x)=\sum c_nx^n$, then $f(ax+b)=\sum c_n(ax+b)^n=\sum\left(\sum{n \choose k}c_k\right)x^n$ which is explicit and not recurrent. I did the calculations for $k(0)$, $k'(0)$, $k''(0)$ on paper, and it seemed possible to me to find a formula for that using induction (which is - you are right - some kind of recurrence)

Comment: Many thanks again. I see you point though :-)

Comment: I messed up the binomial formula in the last comment, but I am glad you see my point :)